# How to convert JavaScript array into Java array

Tags: java, javascript, arrays

I'm trying to rewrite some JavaScript logic found JavaScript functions.
Could you please help me to put this JavaScript array in some Java compatible object so I could loop over all it's elemnets?

I need this as hardcoded array inside Java function.

The main problem for me is that it could contain arrays inside array.

```
this.contract = [
        ["ContractNetworkId",24],
        ["ContractProvider",8],
        ["ContractTariff",16],
        ["ContractSerialNumber",32],
        ["ContractCustomerInfoBitmap",2,[
            ["ContractCustomerProfile",6],
            ["ContractCustomerNumber",32]
        ]],
        ["ContractPassengerInfoBitmap",2, [
            ["ContractPassengerClass",8],
            ["ContractPassengerTotal",8]
        ]],
        ["ContractVehicleClassAllowed",6],
        ["ContractPaymentPointer",32],
        ["ContractPayMethod",11],
        ["ContractServices",16],
        ["ContractPriceAmount",16],
        ["ContractPriceUnit",16],
        ["ContractRestrictionBitmap",7,[
            ["ContractRestrictStart",11],
            ["ContractRestrictEnd",11],
            ["ContractRestrictDay",8],
            ["ContractRestrictTimeCode",8],
            ["ContractRestrictCode",8],
            ["ContractRestrictProduct",16],
            ["ContractRestrictLocation",16]
        ]].....
```

Comment: What about defining each complex structure in the javascript array into java objects? Then add them to a List<Object> = new ArrayList<Object>();. Iterate the list, checking what object instance the elements represent and then handling them accordingly.

Comment: An option would be to use a JSON library here, and then serialize that to a POJO

Comment: Do you need to completely rewrite it in java?

Answer (score 1):

Make a new class to represent the complex object, since they all have a `label` and a `value`. Since one of their attributes can be a `list` of the same object you can add it as well.

Something like:

```
public class CustomObject{
    private String label;
    private int value;
    private List<CustomObject> coList;

    public CustomObject(String label, int value){
       this.label=label;
       this.value=value;
    }

    public CustomObject(String label, int value, List coList){
       this.label=label;
       this.value=value;
       this.coList=coList;
    }

    //getters and setters for the attributes

}
```

Then, create a `List<CustomObject> myCustomObjList=new ArrayList<CustomObject>()` in you data holder class in which you would add the elements:

```
myCustomObjList.add(new CustomObject("label",1)); //no list

final CustomObject obj2=new CustomObject("label2",2);
final List<CustomObject> tmpList=new ArrayList<CustomObject>();
tmpList.add(obj2);
myCustomObjList.add(new CustomObject("label",3,tmpList)); //CustomObject with a list
```

and so on...

You can then iterate the list to get the values as needed. Check the `list` attribute of each CustomObject for `null` first, if it's not `null`, iterate through it as well.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<CustomObject> myCustomObjList = new ArrayList<CustomObject>();
        List<CustomObject> tmpList = new ArrayList<CustomObject>();

        myCustomObjList.add(new CustomObject("ContractNetworkId", 24));
        myCustomObjList.add(new CustomObject("ContractProvider", 8));
        myCustomObjList.add(new CustomObject("ContractTariff", 16));
        myCustomObjList.add(new CustomObject("ContractSerialNumber", 32));

        CustomObject obj1 = new CustomObject("ContractCustomerProfile", 6);
        CustomObject obj2 = new CustomObject("ContractCustomerNumber", 32);

        tmpList.add(obj1);
        tmpList.add(obj2);

        myCustomObjList.add(new CustomObject("ContractCustomerInfoBitmap", 2, tmpList));

        tmpList=new ArrayList<CustomObject>();

        obj1 = new CustomObject("ContractPassengerClass", 8);
        obj2 = new CustomObject("ContractPassengerTotal", 8);

        tmpList.add(obj1);
        tmpList.add(obj2);        

        myCustomObjList.add(new CustomObject("ContractPassengerInfoBitmap", 2, tmpList));

        for (CustomObject parent : myCustomObjList) {
            System.out.print(parent.getLabel()+" ; ");
            System.out.println(parent.getValue());

            if (parent.getCoList() != null) {
                for (CustomObject child : parent.getCoList()) {
                    System.out.print("  "+child.getLabel()+" ");
                    System.out.println(child.getValue());
                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(" Parent does not contain children");
            }
        }
        tmpList.clear();
    }
```

would produce the output:

```
ContractNetworkId ; 24
 Parent does not contain children
ContractProvider ; 8
 Parent does not contain children
ContractTariff ; 16
 Parent does not contain children
ContractSerialNumber ; 32
 Parent does not contain children
ContractCustomerInfoBitmap ; 2
  ContractCustomerProfile 6
  ContractCustomerNumber 32
ContractPassengerInfoBitmap ; 2
  ContractPassengerClass 8
  ContractPassengerTotal 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ContractDetail[][] contractDetails = { { new ContractDetail(24, "ContractNetworkId") },
                { new ContractDetail(2, "ContractPassengerInfoBitmap") },
                { new ContractDetail(8, "ContractPassengerClass"), new ContractDetail(8, "ContractPassengerTotal") } };

        for (ContractDetail[] contractDetailsAryOuter : contractDetails) {
            for (ContractDetail contractDetailInnter : contractDetailsAryOuter) {
                System.out.println("Contract Property: " + contractDetailInnter.getId() + ";"
                        + contractDetailInnter.getContractProperty());
            }
        }
    }

}

class ContractDetail {
    private int id;
    private String contractProperty;

    public ContractDetail(int id, String contractProperty) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.contractProperty = contractProperty;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getContractProperty() {
        return contractProperty;
    }

    public void setContractProperty(String contractProperty) {
        this.contractProperty = contractProperty;
    }
}
```